# Puzzling Query Performance Results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on trying to optimize some queries and am getting some puzzling results (probably stemming from my limited understanding of the inner workings of MySQL).

The baffling thing (at least to me at this point) is that when I was trying to dissect the complete query to optimize it I found that the inner select query (the sub-query) runs much, much more slowly on its own; I thought that the simpler query would run faster.  Bellow are the queries and my results:

### The Complete Query

```
SELECT r.id, r.serve_url, r.title, r.category_id, GROUP_CONCAT(hr.server_id) AS server_id
FROM hosted_resources hr
LEFT JOIN resources AS r ON (hr.resource_id = r.id)
WHERE hr.resource_id = (
    select id from resources
    where resource_type_id = 1
    and category_id = 1
    and id < 311
    order by date_added desc
    limit 1
)
GROUP BY r.id, r.serve_url, r.title, r.category_id;
```

result of the EXPLAIN query:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys                                                                 | key                                          | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | hr        | ref   | hosted_resources_resource_id_resource_id_idx,hosted_resources_resource_id_idx | hosted_resources_resource_id_resource_id_idx | 4       | const |    2 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | r         | const | PRIMARY                                                                       | PRIMARY                                      | 4       | const |    1 |                                                           |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | resources | ref   | PRIMARY,type_idx,category_idx,type_category_idx,type_category_date_idx        | type_category_date_idx                       | 8       |       |   87 | Using where; Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Benchmarking results:

```
Concurrency Level:      5000
Time taken for tests:   9.396 seconds
Complete requests:      100000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Non-2xx responses:      100000
Total transferred:      31900000 bytes
HTML transferred:       16900000 bytes
Requests per second:    10642.78 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       469.802 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.094 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          3315.47 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

---

## The Sub-Query (which I had expected to run faster)

```
select id, serve_url, title, category_id from resources
where resource_type_id = 1
and category_id = 1
and id < 311
order by date_added desc
limit 1
```

Results of the EXPLAIN query:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys                                                          | key                    | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | resources | ref  | PRIMARY,type_idx,category_idx,type_category_idx,type_category_date_idx | type_category_date_idx | 8       | const,const |   87 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
```

Benchmarking results:

```
Concurrency Level:      5000
Time taken for tests:   42.181 seconds
Complete requests:      100000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      41800000 bytes
HTML transferred:       27100000 bytes
Requests per second:    2370.75 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2109.040 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.422 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          967.75 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

The resources table:

```
CREATE TABLE `resources` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 
  `resource_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT,
  `resource_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 
  `is_hosted` bit(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 
  `serve_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 
  `parent_resource_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `serve_url_UNIQUE` (`serve_url`),
  KEY `type_idx` (`resource_type_id`),
  KEY `status_idx` (`resource_status_id`),
  KEY `category_idx` (`category_id`),
  KEY `resources_parent_resource_id_idx` (`parent_resource_id`),
  KEY `type_category_idx` (`resource_type_id`,`category_id`),
  KEY `date_added_idx` (`date_added`),
  KEY `type_category_date_idx` (`resource_type_id`,`category_id`,`date_added`),
  CONSTRAINT `resources_category_id` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `resources_parent_resource_id` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_resource_id`) REFERENCES `resources` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `resources_resource_status_id` FOREIGN KEY (`resource_status_id`) REFERENCES `resource_statuses` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `resources_resource_type_id` FOREIGN KEY (`resource_type_id`) REFERENCES `resource_types` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=598 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Any toughs would be much, much appreciated.
kate

Comment: which indexes do you have on the tables ? First thing I am seeing on the explain , is that the second query is not using any indexes, meanwhile is uses one in the first query which explain the much faster time

Comment: Ph.T - I have added the table structure.

Comment: I want to understand the structure of your DB , how many records approx of type "resource_type_id = 1 and category_id = 1" and of type "id < 311" do you have in the database ? how many total recods do you have in the table ? how often do you need to use this query ? do you use many other queries ? the point is , may be the indexes you have are not usefull, maybe we can give a hint to mysql

Comment: @Kate . . . What version of MySQL are you using?  Version 5.6 introduced some new optimization methods, and it might be recognizing your construct as a correlated subquery.

Comment: Is the question here why the subquery runs slower on its own or is it how to optimize the whole thing, or both?

Comment: What version of mysql are you running? Also, could this not be re-stated without the subquery?

Comment: at a glance, having id < 311 i guess it's the main index you may use since it's a tiny subset of your huge table ( for the time it uses), you could give a first hint to see what's happening: select ... from resources use index (id) ... check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html

Comment: I'm using version 5.5.  This query is used A LOT; it is one of the main queries used on a rather busy system which can have 5K - 10K users connected at any given time, and this query is used at least once a minute by each user.  The table itself is not that big, having under 5K records; half of the records are of resource_type_id = 1 and about 30% category_id = 1.

Comment: N.B.  Good question :)  my ultimate goal is to optimize; while trying to optimize I came across this results which I found puzzling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your queries are not comparable, when you are running the subquery on it's own it has additional columns, I believe this is where the difference arises, you can see the extra for the subquery in the EXPLAIN for your main query has:

```
Using where; Using index
```

When you run the subquery on it's own with additional columns it only shows:

```
Using where
```

The reason for this is that your nonclustered indexes only store the indexed columns, and the primary key, so your index:

```
KEY `type_category_date_idx` (`resource_type_id`,`category_id`,`date_added`)
```

has enough information in to satisfy your entire subquery:

```
SELECT ID
FROM   Resources
WHERE  resource_type_id = 1
  AND  category_id = 1
  AND  id < 311
ORDER BY date_added DESC
```

It is therefore not necessary to refer back to the table data. When you add more columns to the select list the index no longer holds all the information required to satisfy the query, and the query needs to perform a bookmark lookup back to the table data using the list of ids from the index, and find the data in the relevant columns.

This is what the [My SQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html#explain_extra) say about `Using Index`:

> *The column information is retrieved from the table using only information in the index tree without having to do an additional seek
>   to read the actual row. This strategy can be used when the query uses
>   only columns that are part of a single index.*
>
> *If the Extra column also says Using where, it means the index is being used to perform lookups of key values. Without Using where, the
>   optimizer may be reading the index to avoid reading data rows but not
>   using it for lookups. For example, if the index is a covering index
>   for the query, the optimizer may scan it without using it for
>   lookups.*

You should see that if you run your subquery only using `SELECT ID FROM...` that you get the same plan as in the main query, and a much quicker execution time than running it with additional columns.

**EDIT**

In terms of actually optimising your query, I think you can change your `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` since you know the ID must exist in`resources` based on the `WHERE` clause. Other than that, I don't see much scope for improvement, although I believe MySQL will deal with JOINs better than a subquery in the where Clause, so the following may perform better:

```
SELECT  r.id, r.serve_url, r.title, r.category_id, GROUP_CONCAT(hr.server_id) AS server_id
FROM    resources r
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  ID
            FROM    Resources
            WHERE   resource_type_id = 1
            AND     category_id = 1
            AND     id < 311
            ORDER BY date_added DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ) MaxR
            ON MaxR.ID = r.ID
        INNER JOIN hosted_resources hr
            ON hr.resource_id = r.id
GROUP BY r.id, r.serve_url, r.title, r.category_id;
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was a silly omission/change on my part.  The query did execute much faster without the extra columns.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the key:

```
KEY `type_category_date_idx` (`resource_type_id`,`category_id`,`date_added`)
```

This key contains other keys stated above. From what I know mysql can use 2 different keys at once. If these three are very frequently used for lookups into this table the key may not be so simple to remove.

Comment: Hmm, originally I didn't have that index, but have added it based on the EXPLAIN results.  The benchmarking results showed a speed up of about 5 seconds.

Comment: Keep in mind when running your benchmarks not to restart mysql. Depending on your table types it needs to be accessed many times to load all the tables into RAM and a restart with flush those caches.